# Proxy configuration in Internet Explorer using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-9, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to set some proxy setting in internet explorer with the help of webdriver.

Currently I am using this code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Path to IEDriverServer.exe");
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
    proxy.setProxyAutoconfigUrl("proxyhost:port");
    DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
    capability.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer().getBrowserName());
    capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy); 
    driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(capability);
```

But it does nothing except giving this message on console :

```
org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.WindowsProxyManager backupRegistrySettings
INFO: Backing up registry settings...
```

I have done the settings related to zone and all which are necessary for using IEDriver.

I am able to use Internet explorer through webdriver without using Proxy configuration.

**I am using IE9 on Windows 7 with IEDriver.exe version 2.28.0.**

Can somebody suggest me some work around for this.Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround : Set the PAC file manually in IE.  Simply launch the IEdriver.  The bad part is is you would keep switching it if u use IE for surfing..